# Centralize navigation buttons on page in mobile view

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a site with two bootstrap buttons on the right navigation bar named Demo and Login.

While they look perfectly fine on desktop.
But on mobile the buttons just overlap each other on the right of the screen.

I what the buttons to dropdown and be centralized beneath the header on mobile.
[desktop menu view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHarn.png)
 [expected mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSLl4.png)

```
<div class="align-self-center ml-auto header-col-right">
        <a class="btn-custom" href="#"><i 
            class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>-->Demo</a>
        <a class="btn-custom" href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>-->Login</a>
        <span id="menu-btn"></span>
                       
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

How can this be achieved.

Comment: @media-query (min-width:350px) and (max-width:650px){
      #menu {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        right: 50%;
      }
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the menu position to absolute

I add an id to the menu to make it easier to reach

```
                   <div id='menu' class="align-self-center ml-auto header-col-right">
                        <a class="btn-custom" href="#"><!--<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>-->Demo</a>
                        <a class="btn-custom" href="#"><!--<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>-->Login</a>
                        <span id="menu-btn"></span>
                   
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
```

And in the style do

```
    <style>
      #menu {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        right: 50%;
      }
    </style>
```

Comment: @bharti thanks for your help. But this did not do the job for me. Here is a limk to the site http://test.advertigital.com/

Comment: Oh now I know  What is the problem you simply put display: grid-template-columns: 100%; but you need to put the header height to height: fit-content; I try this and it work

Comment: hello @walid behzoui can you please help with the css script u used to make this work for better understanding.

Comment: @tegah are you looking for this result https://ibb.co/sjpbY8L

Comment: Yes @Walid Bezoui thats exactly what am looking for.